# Why does this apt-key adv command give an error?

Tags: docker

This is a snippet of a Dockerfile that is exhibiting an error that I don't understand:

```
FROM dorowu/ubuntu-desktop-lxde-vnc
LABEL maintainer "bpinaya@wpi.edu"

# Adding keys for ROS
RUN sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'
RUN apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-key 421C365BD9FF1F717815A3895523BAEEB01FA116
```

Gives this result

```
RUN apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-key 421C365BD9FF1F717815A3895523BAEEB01FA116
 ---> Running in 7bb30729ec87
Warning: apt-key output should not be parsed (stdout is not a terminal)
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.HkofyyhjvI/gpg.1.sh --keyserver hkp://ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-key 421C365BD9FF1F717815A3895523BAEEB01FA116
gpg: failed to start the dirmngr '/usr/bin/dirmngr': No such file or directory
gpg: connecting dirmngr at '/tmp/apt-key-gpghome.HkofyyhjvI/S.dirmngr' failed: No such file or directory
gpg: keyserver receive failed: No dirmngr
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-key 421C365BD9FF1F717815A3895523BAEEB01FA116' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this post [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/401547/gpg-keyserver-receive-failed-no-dirmngr), you need to install dirmngr.  I also needed to install gnupg in order to get this to work on my local docker container when testing.

I updated your Dockerfile code below with my changes:

```
FROM dorowu/ubuntu-desktop-lxde-vnc
LABEL maintainer "bpinaya@wpi.edu"

# Update
RUN apt-get update && \
  apt-get upgrade -y

# Install required packages
RUN apt-get install -y \
  dirmngr \
  gnupg

# Adding keys for ROS
RUN sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'

RUN apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-key 421C365BD9FF1F717815A3895523BAEEB01FA116
```

This gave me the following output on the last step:

```
Step 6/6 : RUN apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://pgp.mit.edu:80 --recv-key 421C365BD9FF1F717815A3895523BAEEB01FA116
 ---> Running in a0cfb3588173
Warning: apt-key output should not be parsed (stdout is not a terminal)
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.USze27holj/gpg.1.sh --keyserver hkp://pgp.mit.edu:80 --recv-key 421C365BD9FF1F717815A3895523BAEEB01FA116
gpg: key 5523BAEEB01FA116: public key "ROS Builder <rosbuild@ros.org>" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1
```

Occasionally this reports back with the following error:

```
gpg: keyserver receive failed: Cannot assign requested address
```

That error doesn't seem consistent though, so it could be something with my own network connection.

Comment: THanks.  I ran it three times like you proposed, and twice I got that error, and once not. So, it worked, I guess, but I don't love non-deterministic dockerfiles!

Comment: You may also have luck with hkp://pgp.mit.edu or hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com which should both work as alternatives.  People sometimes report problems with the keyserver you selected to use.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to comment but don't have enough reputation to. Please consider my answer as an appendix to @brian-elliott 's answer. Dirmngr seems to have some strange default setup to use tor or some non-standard DNS. So make sure you have something like this:

```
standard-resolver
keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com
keyserver keys.gnupg.net
```

in your ~/.gnupg/dirmngr.conf